# Microchip's MPLAB-X IDE have wrong fonts and unreadable tabs

Tags: fonts, ide

After installing Microchip's [MPlab X IDE](http://www.microchip.com/mplab/mplab-x-ide) on a recent (16.04 or up) Ubuntu Linux, I have the fonts in the main interface "wrong": they are cut, and the tabs are way too small to be readable:

[image: Bad looking MPlab X ide]

I tried to change fonts, but the fonts selectable are only the fonts internal to the panes, and they are already ok. Is it fixable?

Comment: Hope it helps. It drove me crazy for the last month...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's a bit hidden though. Choose `Tools` `->` `Options` on the main menu, go to the Appearance tab, the to the `Look and Feel` subtab, and choose for example "Nimbus":

[image: Choose non-GTK+ look'n'fell]

Restart your IDE (you will be prompted by the program itself to do it) and *voilà*:

[image: Correctly displayed MPLAB-X]